# Fixar footer quando usuario scrollar até o elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou fazendo uma landing page que tem um footer entre as sections, e quando o usuario scrollar até esse footer ele deve ficar fixo no bottom.

Tentei usar scrollToFixed mas ele se comporta como um header, fixo ao topo.

Tem como alterar esse plugin ou jeito mais simples de fazer?

```css
ul{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}


ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px
 }

section{
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px 10px; 
} 

.footer-contato{
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>informações</li>
      <li>localização</li>
      <li>patrocinadores</li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
</header>
<section class="home">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
<section class="informacoes">
    <h1>Informações</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
<section class="footer-contato">
  <h1> Footer fixed </h1>
</section>
<section class="local">
    <h1>Local</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
<section class="patrocinadores">
    <h1>Patrocinadores</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: O lugar do Footer é no meio mesmo ? Daí quando o usuário chegar até o Footer é pra ele ir lá no Bottom ?

Comment: Veja um exemplo que fiz: http://jsfiddle.net/ckvda5L3/ ... tem a ver com isso ou eu entendi errado ?

Comment: ele deve ficar fixo no bottom só quando ele aparecer pro usuario, durante a rolagem @DeeSouza

Comment: Haaa. Entendi... Vou ver se consigo simular.

Comment: E quando subir tem que voltar no lugar ?

Comment: Sim, volta pro lugar com position relative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(window).width() > 992) {
        var altura = $('#video').offset().top;
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > altura) {
            $(".footer-contato").addClass('fixar');
        } else {
            $(".footer-contato").removeClass('fixar');
        }
    }
});
```